# iphone sdk: unedited sms body

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk

I am creating an application that sends SMS while after click on a button. To implement SMS functionality I used [MFMessageComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009668). But when I click on my button to send SMS the MessageUI view controller is displayed along with my custom SMS body.
 I dont want to let user edit SMS body, I just need to send the SMS as it is.

Can any one help me in solving this.?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not prevent user from editing sms body.

Comment: If you could, it would mean you also could program an app that sends overcharge sms silently. It would be extremely nasty.